# Configure subdomain port forwarding on EC2 VPC

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am running a Linux instance on EC2. It is running **Apache** on port `80` and a custom **nodejs server** on port `8080`.

I would like to use a subdomain to redirect the petitions from port `80` to `8080`. 
Traffic to `nodejs.mydomain.com:80` should be redirected to the `EC2` server on port `8080`.

Is that possible using AWS VPC?
I do not want to configure Apache as a proxy.

More details about the current configuration:

- The instance has attached an Elastic IP address.
- I'm using Route 53 to point my domain to this IP
- The instance is running inside a VPC
- The server is on production so I'm looking for a minimum downtime

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not possible via VPC settings. You have to use a reverse proxy like Apache or Nginx for this.

Comment: Thank you Mark! At least I will not spend more time checking VPC.